# Accessing Commerce ‘Product Fields’ in events hooks

Tags: craft3, events, modules, plugin-craftcommerce3

I've added an Entries field called `linkedCourseEntry` to a Product (Product Type > Product Fields tab). In the Product itself I've assigned an entry.

I need to access `linkedCourseEntry` from one or more Events, but can’t work out how to do so.

For example when `EVENT_POPULATE_LINE_ITEM` is used:

```
Event::on(
    LineItems::class,
    LineItems::EVENT_POPULATE_LINE_ITEM,
    function(LineItemEvent $event) {

        $lineItem = $event->lineItem;
        $purchasable = $lineItem->getPurchasable();

        // Somehow access the 'linkedCourseEntry' data here... help! 
    }
);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
$purchasable->product->yourEntriesFieldHandle->one()->title
```

Comment: Yes. Brilliant. Thank you. I'd love to know 'how' you know that? I've not been able to find this indicated in the docs, and of I take a look at the $purchasable object I don't see 'product' as an item. Cheers though!

Comment: I knew this because $purchasable is an instance of a Variant, and all variants have a parent product. If you dump out $purchasable (`Craft::dd($purchasable);`) you can see that it's a Variant and has a nested object representing the Product. Here's the relevant part of the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-elements-variant.html#product